# texinfo: Can I write non-english info files? Such as Chinese, and how?

Tags: man, locale, gnu, info

Most gnu manual files use `info`, write a `texinfo` then `makeinfo` produces info files, it's great.

Can texinfo contain non-English characters then produce non-English infos or pdfs?

How can I write Chinese info manuals? What is the best solutions for non-English software manuals, documentations just one source files to info, man, html, and pdf.

Answer (score 5):

[Sphinx](http://sphinx-doc.org/) can build into all of these format using special [builders](http://sphinx-doc.org/builders.html).

The input format is UTF-8, so Chinese should be OK (I have only used French and Spanish non-ASCII characters).

Answer (score 3):

You can write texinfo file in chinese by UTF-8 encoding.
In this case, you should set @documentencoding variable to UTF-8.
For more detail, please read [texinfo manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/texinfo/manual/texinfo/html_node/_0040documentencoding.html#g_t_0040documentencoding).

I download latest texinfo-5.2.tar.xz from GNU site.
This includes some files for testing.
And in these file, tp/t/input_files/japanese_utf8.texi is written in Japanese using UTF-8 encoding was succesfully converted to info, and html format in Japanese.